# what is meant by devel for openssl?

Tags: openssl

Am trying to use OpenSSL. But I get the error saying 'libs' dir not found in OpenSSL directory.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-       L/Users/user56023/Documents/Software/openssl-1.0.1h/lib'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Very much true that I couldn't find the 'lib' directory in OpenSSL directory. I tried searching about this error & got to this:
http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2008-05/0125.html

The reply says to install devel package. What does this mean? Is 'devel' another software or is it a short form for 'development' package in OpenSSL? From where do I download it? Can someone please help?

Comment: Related: [What does -devel mean when installing a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7941068/4722345)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct - it's short for "development package".

For Linux, you need a command like this:

`yum install openssl openssl-devel # for Redhat/Centos/openSUSE`

`apt-get install openssl openssl-dev # for Debian/Ubuntu`

Note: these commands use the "package manager" to install *both* openssl (which it sounds like you already have: but it wouldn't hurt to do an install), and openssl-devel.

Comment: I use Mac. Can you please say how do I do this in Mac?

Comment: Let me try with HomeBrew. Thanks @FoggyDay ! Will get back!

Comment: Tried HomeBrew on Mac. I gave the command "brew install openssl openssl-dev", but it fails with the error :
"Error: No available formula for openssl-dev"

Comment: These two links might help: [OpenSSL Version MacOSX Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/openssl-version-macosx-homebrew and [OpenSSL - Compiling a Web Development Environment on MacOSX](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/openssl/)

Comment: Thanks @FoggyDay ! Will check out & be back!